# Cannot get BCrypt autentication to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I am trying to set up a simple iOS/Rails application where I can create a user and subsequently authenticate them using BCrypt. I have tried to follow BCrypt's instructions but my authentication process is not working. Very new to rails so I'm sure I'm screwing up something simple!

To create a new user:

In users_controller.rb

```
# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.password = user_params[:password]

 respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
end
```

In user.rb

```
def password
   @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
end

def password=(new_password)
   @password = Password.create(new_password)
   self.password_hash = @password
end
```

On the server:

*Started POST "/users.json" for 192.168.2.6 at 2014-08-21 19:32:05 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"username"=>"testtest", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"username"=>"testtest"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (20.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" = 'testtest' LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_hash`
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "password_hash", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-22 00:32:05.960378"], ["password_hash", "$2a$10$UzLdD7ytQXKRDU5MhAawJuFQ3R4oQlPyXh/V4GehNP692fsSpK6wK"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-22 00:32:05.960378"], ["username", "testtest"]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered users/show.json.jbuilder (0.3ms)
Completed 201 Created in 136ms (Views: 31.9ms | ActiveRecord: 23.5ms)*

The authenticate a user:

In sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
    if @user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        render :show
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
        render :action => 'fail'
    end
end
```

In user.rb

```
def self.authenticate(username,password)
 @user = User.find_by_username(username)
 return @user.password == password
end
```

Server:

*Started POST "/session" for 192.168.2.6 at 2014-08-21 19:38:26 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"username"=>"testtest", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"username"=>"testtest", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" = 'testtest' LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/fail.json.jbuilder (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 23.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)*

Thanks much for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Bcrypt is used to encrypt password.

You can use this following method in `user.rb` model to encrypt the password and authenticate user.

```
before_save :encrypt_password
def self.authenticate(name, password)
  user = find_by_user_name(name)
  if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
  else
    nil
  end
end

def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a few other issues with my code but this helped immensely.